# SQL Query of checking existing entry in database is not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php
          error_reporting(0);
          $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "checksql"); 

          if($link === false){
            die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
          }

          $myemailaddress=$_POST['useremail']; 
          $mypassword=$_POST['userpassword'];

          $sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM register WHERE Email = '$myemailaddress' ");
          $count = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
          echo $count;

          if($count > 0){
            echo "success";
          } else{
            echo "failed";
          }
       ?>
```

I am trying to check whether an email exists in the database or not. I searched different thread on stackoverflow and tried to correct it but failed. Even the echo of $count isn't showing it's value. Is there any other way to check it?

Comment: `error_reporting(0);` disables error reporting. Remove that line and post the error message, please.

Comment: Looks like you want to check whether an email has "already been used" for registration and deny using it again. Instead of using a race-condition prone SELECT-then-INSERT combo, do that with a unique contraint on the Email field in your table definition and then check for the specific error code ER_DUP_KEY. see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html

Comment: You need to pass the connection into the query function when using the procedural approach. `$sql = mysqli_query($link, QUERY);` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php Also you shouldn't pass user input direct to your query this opens you to SQL injections.

Comment: if `$count` is zero ( 0 ) then echo'ing it out will generally show nothing as zero is considered false. Are you expecting a value greater than zero?

Comment: @chris85 darn it, saw your comment soon as I posted my answer.

Comment: so, where are we with this question? there are quite a few unknowns which I have made points about in my answer below. Go over it carefully and check for errors while making sure there are no spaces in your db's data and your inputs.

Comment: Your code must check the error result of the query. Get into this habit and you will avoid issues like this in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't pass db connection to your query

```
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT ...
                    ^^^^^^
```

Btw, your code is open to SQL injection.

Use a prepared statement

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

More on SQL injection:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection
- http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php
- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Also make sure your POST arrays are not failing you.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

- `error_reporting(0);` doesn't help you, it turns it off.

Add `or die(mysqli_error($link))` to `mysqli_query()` to check for errors.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- Your form should be using a POST method with name attributes for both your POSTs. That is unclear and wasn't posted in your question; call it an insight.

If you are using both your form and PHP/MySQL inside the same file, then that will trigger undefined index notices on initial page load.

- Use `!empty()` for them.

Reference(s):

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: At first I really want to thank you so much for helping me this much. Actually I am just learning php html css and in a beginner stage. So I didn't know so many informations but thanks to you I can study about them now. Problem solved.

Comment: @ArnabDas You're very much welcome Arnab, I'm glad to have been of help and that my answer helped solved it, *cheers*